# How do I insert rows into one table from another that don't already exist in the target table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy rows from Table2 into Table1 as long as they don't already exist in Table1. Right now I get the generic errors `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` and `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.`

```
 DECLARE @UserID varchar(100)
 SET @UserID = 'me'

 INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col7,
                        Col8, Col9, Col5, Col6)
            (SELECT 2 AS [Col1], Col2, Col3, Col4, Col7,
                        Col8s, GETDATE() AS [Col9],  @UserID AS [Col5], GETDATE() AS [Col6]
            FROM Table2 AS bpt)
            WHERE (SELECT (CONVERT(varchar(10), Col2) + Col3 + Col4) FROM Table2) NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT (CONVERT(varchar(10), Col2) + Col3 + Col4) FROM Table1)
```

Comment: Look up `LEFT JOIN` in your SQL reference.  Also, your use of parentheses around the `SELECT ... FROM Table2` statement is odd. Finally, the `NOT EXISTS` syntax is `WHERE NOT EXISTS (<Contitions>)`

Comment: Google how to use `EXISTS`.  That's not the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query to create the select statement for insertion in table 1.

```
SELECT col1,col2
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1,col2 
                  FROM table1
                  WHERE table1.pk = table2.pk);
```

PK ----> Primary key

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have primary keys to match on , try something  like this

```
INSERT Table1 (col1,col2)
SELECT col1,col2 from
(
     SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2
     EXCEPT
     SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE1
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I prefer the organization of a `MERGE` statement over an `INSERT`, even though if all you do is insert with the `MERGE` then they are effectively the same thing.

In your case it allows you can compare each key as you would naturally do in a join, instead of concatenating strings to make a massive key.

```
MERGE table1 AS tgt
USING (
    SELECT 2 AS [Col1], Col2, Col3, Col4, Col7,
        Col8, GETDATE() AS [Col9],  @UserID AS [Col5], GETDATE() AS [Col6]
    FROM Table2
) AS src
ON src.Col2 = tgt2.Col2 AND src.Col3 = tgt.Col3 AND src.Col4 = tgt.Col4
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9)
    VALUES (src.Col1, src.Col2, src.Col3, src.Col4, src.Col5, src.Col6, src.Col7, src.Col8, src.Col9)
```

Here's an alternative method where you left join to the table and keep all that don't match.  It'll work but I feel the logic on the merge is more straight forward.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Col1, Col2, /* ... */ Col9)
SELECT src.Col1, src.Col2, /* ... */ Col9)
FROM (
   SELECT 2 AS [Col1], Col2, Col3, Col4, Col7,
       Col8, GETDATE() AS [Col9],  @UserID AS [Col5], GETDATE() AS [Col6]
   FROM Table2
) src
LEFT JOIN table1 tgt ON tgt.Col2 = src.Col2 AND tgt2.Col3 = src.Col3 AND tgt.Col4 = src.Col4
WHERE tgt.[PrimaryKey] IS NULL -- keep rows where there was no match to table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original query as the base, here are both the LEFT JOIN and IF NOT EXISTS versions of the query:

```
 DECLARE @UserID varchar(100)
 SET @UserID = 'me'

INSERT INTO Table1 (
    Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, 
    Col7, Col8, Col9, Col5, 
    Col6)
SELECT 2 AS [Col1], 
    Col2, Col3, Col4, Col7,
    Col8s, GETDATE() AS [Col9], 
    @UserID AS [Col5], 
    GETDATE() AS [Col6]
FROM Table2 AS bpt
LEFT JOIN Table1 as exc
    ON bpt.Col2 = exc.Col2
    AND bpt.Col3 = exc.Col3
    AND bpt.Col4 = exc.Col4
WHERE bpt.Col2 IS NULL

-- Alternate version using EXISTS:
DECLARE @UserID varchar(100)
SET @UserID = 'me'

INSERT INTO Table1 (
    Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, 
    Col7, Col8, Col9, Col5, 
    Col6)
SELECT 2 AS [Col1], 
    Col2, Col3, Col4, Col7,
    Col8s, GETDATE() AS [Col9], 
    @UserID AS [Col5], 
    GETDATE() AS [Col6]
FROM Table2 AS bpt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE bpt.Col2 = exc.Col2
        AND bpt.Col3 = exc.Col3
        AND bpt.Col4 = exc.Col4
    )
```

I don't recommend the MERGE version for inserting if the row does not exist solely because MERGE is slower than either of these options.

Comment: MERGE isn't necessarily slower when just doing the insert.  The tests from the article below showed almost exactly the same performance when replacing an insert with a merge http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MERGE/103127/.

Comment: You are correct that it isn't necessarily slower - but if you don't test, you can't tell. MERGE has a particular reputation for slowness in all operations against large datasets.  Also, as discussed [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), MERGE has some subtle bugs that can trip you up through at least 2012 and 2014 (I haven't seen comments specifically about this for 2016+)